# Cannot pass the value to display in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am newbie in Jquery. I tried these coding but not success when it is not display out what I input, and it is only show out 'undefined' when i type any word. Just wonder what are the reason.

```js
    function myFunction() {
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("#h01").val();
            $("#h02").val($('#h01').val());
        });
        
        //$("#h02").attr("style","color:black;font-size:15px").html("Hello jQuery")
    }

    function iwanttochangecolor() { 
        if (i>2){
            i=0;
        }   
        
        $("#h02").attr("style","color:"+arraycolor[i]+";"+"font-size:"+arraysize[i])
        //$("#h01").attr("style","font-size:"+arraysize[i]);
        i++;
    }
    
    function copyText2() {
        h01 = document.getElementById("h01");
        h02 = document.getElementById("h02");
        h02.value = h01.value;
    }
    
    
    $(document).ready(myFunction);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="h01"></h1>
    <p>Input: <input type="text" name="" id="h01" onkeyUp="copyText2()"></p>
    <p>Your input:<input type="text" name="" id="h02" ></p>
    <input type="button" value="Change Color" onclick="iwanttochangecolor()">
```

Comment: First of all, you should break down the javascript from html code, in diferent files(page.html and scripts.js). In Wich function you have de error?

Comment: `$("button").click(function()` change to `$("input[type='button']").click(function()`, as the button like `input` is still a `<input>`, not `<button>`

Comment: You've got 2 elements with the same id: `h01`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's are some reason that break the code:

1. There's no button on your code, so `$("button").click(function(){` should change to `$('input[type="button"]')`.
2. `<h1 id="h01"></h1>` and `<input type="text" name="" id="h01" onkeyUp="copyText2()">` has same `id` h01, change one.
3. Init `i` to 0, as `undefined + 1` is `NaN`, and `NaN + 1` is still `NaN`. And better use var to declare it, not make it a `window`'s attribute.

Fix them and your code should work.

```js
function myFunction() {
        $('input[type="button"]').click(function(){
            $("#h01").val();
            $("#h02").val($('#h01').val());
        });
        
        //$("#h02").attr("style","color:black;font-size:15px").html("Hello jQuery")
    }
    // Fake values. as you use magic number 2, create size 3 array here.
    var arraycolor = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];
     var arraysize = ['small', 'medium', 'large'];
    // Good practice.
    var rotateLength = arraycolor.length;

    // Init i before use.
    var i = 0;
    function iwanttochangecolor() { 
        // Should 
        if (i>2){   // Good practice: use i < rotateLength here
            i=0;
        }   
        
        $("#h02").attr("style","color:"+arraycolor[i]+";"+"font-size:"+arraysize[i])
        //$("#h01").attr("style","font-size:"+arraysize[i]);
        i++;
    }
    
    function copyText2() {
        // Don't make the h01, h02 become global variable, add var.
        var h01 = document.getElementById("h01");
        var h02 = document.getElementById("h02");
        h02.value = h01.value;
    }
    
    
    $(document).ready(myFunction);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="h01h1"></h1>
    <p>Input: <input type="text" name="" id="h01" onkeyUp="copyText2()"></p>
    <p>Your input:<input type="text" name="" id="h02" ></p>
    <input type="button" value="Change Color" onclick="iwanttochangecolor()">
```